# Prevent context cancel from stopping function execution in the middle of business logic

Tags: multithreading, go, go-context

Is there a way to safeguard the execution of business logic from context cancel? Here is the code snippet for a better understanding of my problem

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go foo(ctx)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    cancel()
}

func foo(ctx context.Context) {
    // batch process data
    // context cancel should not stop function execution 
    // in the middle of business logic
    for i:= 0; i<10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("START of business logic for ID:", i)
        fmt.Println("Critical component")
        fmt.Print("Saving changes to DB...")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        fmt.Println("Done")
        fmt.Println("END of business logic for ID:", i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
START of business logic for ID: 0
Critical component
Saving changes to DB...Done
END of business logic for ID: 0
START of business logic for ID: 1
Critical component
Saving changes to DB...Done
END of business logic for ID: 1
START of business logic for ID: 2
Critical component
Saving changes to DB...Done
END of business logic for ID: 2
```

When the execution starts in the for loop, it should not stop until it finishes that iteration. Is this possible with using context cancel? or should I use another approach, please suggest.

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/YSSphRNfl8H)

Comment: What exatly is your question? Your example is not using the context to calcel anything, so it's not clear what part of this you are confused about. The context canlcel is sent through a channel to your go routine, so how you abort is entierly up to you.

Comment: it ends because your prgram exits. It has nothing to do with the context. you did not use it at all.

Comment: @super When I abort is in my control, but what happens when I abort in between of my business logic i.e inside the for loop. I want to prevent go from aborting the function execution while its inside the loop.

Comment: @mh-cbon sorry, in the example I did not use the context but it applies to context as well. Like how can I prevent critical code execution from being aborted by go when the user cancels the HTTP request and the context is cancelled

Comment: by user you mean someone/something hitting your http server ?

Comment: @mh-cbon yes that is one possibility

Comment: @abhijitwakchaure Abort is always in your control. You receive the abort signal from a channel, and you choose what actions to take to abort.

Comment: As @mh-cbon noted the program naturally exits regardless of context cancelation. Better to run the task from the main goroutine - and initiate the cancelation from a secondary goroutine. See below for playground example.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context cancelation is a signal mechanism to a task. It does not ensure enforcement - that is left up to the task. This allows a task to finish up critical sub-tasks before aborting the larger  operation.

So in your theoretical example any critical sub-steps should ignore cancelation - and only after they are complete poll the context:

```
select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err() // we're cancelled, abort
    default:
}
```

---

**EDIT**: applying to your example

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    //
    // critical section
    //

    // ...

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err() // we're cancelled, abort
    default:
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kZ39VEVyP4L

Comment: How can I use my for loop for business logic with select? Can you please share a snippet if possible?

Comment: Thanks @colm.anseo for the playground link, I was cancelling for main.